# Can't set background image in css

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying to set my background image of the page via CSS using the following code, but no image shows up. The image will be tiled on the page and is only 10x10px big. Nonetheless, it still doesn't show up. Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<body>
    <div id="background"></div>
</body>


#background {
background-image: url("img/background.png");
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is the image in `linkToCssFolder/img/background.png`? **The image path is relative to your CSS file.**

Also, does your `#background` div have content in it? If not, it will probably have the default `0px` height, and not show any background.

Comment: You should try changing it to `background-image: url("../img/background.png");` if your CSS is in its own folder.

Comment: So if your CSS file is not in the root (/mystylesheet.css) then you need to change the path accordingly. For example: /styles/mystylesheet.css would use `url(../img/background.png)`.

Comment: It doesn't have any content in, I have changed the code and it still doesn't show up: `#background {
 background-image: url("../img/background.png");
 background-repeat: repeat;
 width: 10px;
 height:  10px;
}`

Comment: What does your file/folder structure look like? (HTML/CSS/images)

Comment: top dir - index.html /img/background.png, /css/style.css

Comment: Have you tried loading the image in HTML with an `<img />` tag? Also, is this live on the internet somewhere?

Comment: Have you properly linked css to html file?

Comment: It shows up with the `img` tag and my link is `<link rel=stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css" />`

Comment: For your file structure, it should be: <link rel=stylesheet href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />

Comment: Try setting your body's background color to a different color (black, for example) - your `background.png` is very light-colored, so it's hard to see. (code: `body{background-color:black;}`)
P.S. Your `<div>` is incorrectly set with width and height to 100% - set it to 10px for each instead.

Comment: I have it working with this code, but I need it to fill the page: `#background {
 background-image: url("../img/background.png");
 background-repeat: repeat;
 width: 500px;
 height:  500px;
}
`

Comment: Just use `body{background-image: url("../img/background.png");}` instead?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the element dimensions too...

```
#background {
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
}
```

Background images do not make their container stretch to fit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [list of all CSS keywords](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp)

Just tried this at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background_multiple and it works.

I assume your image is not at right location or if the background property is being over written by style or another css rule.

Answer (score 1):

such a no brainer thingy of css and html often forgotten even professional due lack of proper focus and just being tired.If you knew it just rest for a while.

here are some tips if you lost in the tree of web design.

1. Check the files if it is there, the file type and support for the file in your browsers
2. Check the directory if you are online you can put all the URL of the file OR use "../" if your css and the image file is in different level of directory.
3. Check your syntax.
4. rest, take a nap or have a coffee break.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your CSS and image location
1) Both in same folder then try " background-image: url("background.jpg") " simply.
2) If you have img folder and image inside this folder then try " background-image: url("img/background.jpg"); "
3)If you have img folder and If you have CSS folder then you have to go one step back then goes to image folder and choose image it seem like this " background-image: url("../img/background.jpg"); " where '..'represent one step back

Comment: These are useful clues for how to refer to an image from relative paths in the stylesheet. However the question already has an accepted answer providing a solution for the real problem (not the paths).

Answer (score 0):

```
#background {background-image: url("img/background.png"); height:300px;}
```

add `height` element in css

Answer (score 0):

Another source of error may come from image extension name, for instance in :
background-image: url("img/background.png")

- Image name must be "background" and NOT "background.png"
- Image "background" must be a PNG and not another image type like JPG

Answer (score -1):

Hy,

to get your image you must imagine that you are in a terminal(or cmd prompt) and write as youuld do to get to the image.

So let us say that your css file is /css/ and you image is in /img/background.png.

To get to the image you must write this code `background-image: url("../img/background.png");`

This is because in terminal/cmd prompt to get to the image from your .css file you would first type cd .., then cd img, then background.png. Hope it will help you!

Cheers!